# Spring - When use DELETE with json returns Bad Request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http

I am developing simple rest api with spring boot. I create users via `POST` method. And deletes via `DELETE`. But when i use `DELETE` with json server returns `Bad Request`.

creating user:

```sh
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"name": "developer", "email": "dev@mail.com"}' http://localhost:8080/add-user

"OK"
```

getting users:

```sh
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ curl  http://localhost:8080

[{"id":"ff80818176c9b9720176c9bdfd0c0002","name":"developer","email":"dev@mail.com"}]
```

deleting user using json:

```sh
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ curl -X DELETE -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"id": "ff80818176c9b9720176c9bdfd0c0002"}' http://localhost:8080/del-id

{"timestamp":"2021-01-03T19:47:15.433+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/del-id"}
```

deleting user using html queries:

```sh
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ curl -X DELETE  http://localhost:8080/del-id?id=ff80818176c9b9720176c9bdfd0c0002

"OK"

ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ curl  http://localhost:8080

[]
```

UserRepository.java

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> {
}
```

UserService.java

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<UserRecord> getAllUsers() {
        List<UserRecord> userRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(userRecords::add);

        return userRecords;
    }

    public void addUser(UserRecord user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void deleteUser(String id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public List<UserRecord> getAllUser() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add-user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpStatus addUser(@RequestBody UserRecord userRecord) {
        userService.addUser(userRecord);

        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/del-id", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public HttpStatus deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);

        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
}
```

jvm log:

```sh
2021-01-03 22:47:15.429  WARN 30785 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'id' is not present]
```

What am i wrong?

Comment: As you can see, the `DELETE` endpoint only needs a parameter (`id`) in the request - not a JSON object. So, this `http://localhost:8080/del-id?id=ff80818176c9b9720176c9bdfd0c0002` is the correct request - if you add it to the body in JSON, then you will get a Bad Request (as the parameter is not where it is supposed to be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spring @RequestParam Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)

The @RequestParam Annotation is designed to derive the value from the URL. When you pass in the id with the requestBody, it's not being populated into the deleteUser function.

Either change the method to also use the @RequestBody annotation or pass in the id through the path param like you do in the html query.

Comment: I updated code by taking attention your answer. It's deletes user but returns `"OK"{"timestamp":"2021-01-04T15:36:41.328+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"","path":"/del-id"}`. Why returning `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` after `"OK"` message?

Comment: Hmm. So you're returning HttpStatus.OK if the method completes successfully, which is where I assume the "OK" comes from, but there must be some error being buried inside the repository method call? Maybe debug from inside the deleteUser method and see if you're hitting some kind of exception?